# Envio automatico de mensajes de whatsapp..!

Tags: php, javascript, whatsapp

He tenido la necesidad como todos de poder crear un aplicativo en mi caso con Php y Js; de enviar mensajes usando el API de Whatsapp. Como muchos ya sabemos es posible enviar con ayuda del link que nos proporciona whatsapp, con ayuda de ese link estoy madurado un poco la idea y queria ver si puedo contar con apoyo de alguno de ustedes para seguir este desarrollo.

Hasta el momento tengo un pequeño aplicativo que te deja escribir el número y el texto despues concatena estas dos variables a la url de api de whatsapp, hasta este paso el aplicativo no es del todo automático ya que después de dar en enviar te redirige a la página de whatsapp es ahí en donde estoy ideando hacer que un script automáticamente presione el botón enviar y cierre la ventana de whatsapp volviendo al aplicativo y poder enviar otro mensaje.

```
var sam = document.getElementsByClassName("_2lkdt");
sam[0].click();
```

En donde `_2lkdt` es la class que se tiene el boton de enviar.
Problemas que he identificado:

1. La clase del boton en cada inicio o recargar la pagina de
   whatsappweb va a cambiar
2. No tengo mucho conocimineto de como realizar el Scrapig js o en php el código que les envio fue probado en la consola de Chorme

Answer (score 4):

**La respuesta breve:** NO SE PUEDE

**La respuesta no tan Breve:**

No se puede ejecutar un boton en una pagina externa desde PHP ya que todos los códigos PHP se ejecutan en el lado del servidor y no del lado del cliente. El código PHP no se ejecuta en ningún navegador, por lo que en esencia no hay ningún enlace para hacer clic, inclusive si intentas hacer web scraping lo unico disponible que vas a tener es la referencia del boton mas sin embargo no vas a poder ejecutar dicho boton.

> Desde luego del lado del servidor puedes ejecutar un evento submit utilizando
>   web scraping sin embargo el boton **'Enviar'** de la pantalla de
>   whatsap no es de tipo submit, por tal motivo no podrias hacerlo de
>   esta forma.

Si quieres guiar cosas del lado del cliente, necesitarías recurrir a robotizador de navegadores como [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/).

Igual te muestro varias soluciones que he realizado para que compruebes por ti mismo:

**Posible solución 1:** Vamos a suponer que haces un POST a un servidor php que redirecciona la pagina luego de cargar ejecutaremos algun script.

*JS:*

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                url: 'whatsap.php',
                data: JSON.stringify({ whatsap: 'https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=numerodetelefonodewhatsapp&text=urldelmensaje' }),
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
            });
```

*PHP:*

```
   <?php 
    $link = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
    header('Location: '. $link['whatsap']);
    exit();
   ?>
```

> Solución 1.. Fallida: **No podemos obtener la pagina desde javascript.**

**Posible solución 2:** Web scraping

*PHP:* (Hare uso de [simple_html_dom](https://github.com/samacs/simple_html_dom) para el web Scraping en PHP de la pagina):

```
<?php

include_once('./simple_html_dom.php');
$url = 'https://api.whatsapp.com/send?';
$data =  http_build_query(array(
    'phone'=>$_POST['phone'],
    'text'=>$_POST['text']
));
$html = file_get_html($url.$data);
$button =  $html->find('#action-button');

var_dump($button); //Aqui tienes el boton pero no puedes ejecutar el evento click.

?>
```

> Solución 2.. Fallida: **No se puede ejecutar un evento click utilizando webScraping.**

**Posible solución 3:** Pintar el contenido de la pagina de whatsap en tu pagina.

*PHP*

```
<?php
$url = 'https://api.whatsapp.com/send?';
$data =  http_build_query(array(
    'phone'=> 'tutelefono',
    'text'=> 'mensaje'
));
$html = file_get_contents($url.$data);
echo $html;

?>
```

> Solución 3.. Fallida: **Recibiras el siguiente mensaje por el equipo de seguridad de whatsap. :(**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: aprecio mucho tu respuesta, con esto me resumes que ¿no existe un método para poder usar Whatsapp para enviar mensajes automáticos?

Comment: Asi es!, al menos de que lo crees tu mismo, utilizando un Robot.

Comment: @SantiagoGutierrez si entiendes que esta es la respuesta correcta favor marcala